# Update openssl to 3.1.1 from 1.0.2n in Nodejs

Tags: ssl, openssl, node.js, ssl-certificate

I am working on an old node.js project which is using the Openssl version 1.0.2n. I found only a **dll** `(libeay32.dll)` using in this project and in that that dll openssl version is 1.0.2n. Since Openssl 1.0.2n is now out of support, I have to update the Openssl version 3.1.0.

I couldn't find such dll that is supporting the Openssl 3.1.0. I am stacked a few days on how to update it. Does there any way to update the dll with required version or do i have to move any alternative way?

Comment: OpenSSL 3.1 is not API compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.2. You cannot simply replace the DLL but need to use a version of nodejs which is compiled against OpenSSL 3